# Modify the .exe's AssemblyInfo using PowerShell in TFS 2018 build

Tags: powershell, tfs, build, assemblyinfo

I want to use PowerShell to update my application's Assembly info like Product Name, File Description in TFS vNext build. I want to use build variables in build definition and pass it to the script.

I have done the same to update version number with the help of this(https://writeabout.net/2015/11/01/set-assembly-and-app-version-to-a-matching-build-name-in-tfs-2015-or-vso-build-vnext/).

I need help with the script to replace "Product Name" or "Description" value with new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the name & description with a small script:

```
Param(
    [string]$filePath,
    [string]$newProductName,
    [string]$newProductDesc
)

$patternProductName = '\[assembly: AssemblyProduct\("(.*)"\)\]'
$patternProductDesc = '\[assembly: AssemblyDescription\("(.*)"\)\]'
(Get-Content $filePath) | ForEach-Object{
     if($_ -match $patternProductName){
           '[assembly: AssemblyProduct("{0}")]' -f $newProductName
     }
     elseif($_ -match $patternProductDesc){
           '[assembly: AssemblyDescription("{0}")]' -f $newProductDesc 
     }
     else{
        $_
     }
} | Set-Content $filePath
```

Now during the build call this script and in the arguments send the 3 args: AssmeblyInfo file path, your new product name and your new product description.

Comment: Small fix variable name wrong  - $patternProductName = '\[assembly: AssemblyDescription\("(.*)"\)\]' should be $patternProductDesc = '\[assembly: AssemblyDescription\("(.*)"\)\]'

Comment: For posterity, I had to put commas after each of the parameters in the Param section.

Comment: @b.pell You're right! I fixed it. thanks!

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Thanks for sharing also, this PowerShell is such a timer saver.